# Interacting with UtilityBar component

Tags: lightning-events, utility-bar

I need to display a record pop using a utility bar.
We have a use case where an external system will accept the phone call and will send us the phone number of the caller. We need to capture this phone number on SF side and do a search within SF to find the associated record and show that as a record pop using utility bar.

As the lightning component embedded in Utility bar is not initialized until we open the utility bar, I am planning to use Background Utility component to listen to streaming events. So that my background utility component can capture the phone number coming from an external system and pass that information to the component present in utility bar. The component in utility bar can then do a search based on Phone number and display the basic attributes of caller as a pop on utility bar component.

I looked at the UtilityBarApi documentation but there is no way to get access to the lightning component present in the utility bar. So I think my only option is to pass information to component present utility bar is via an application event. If anyone has any other alternate solution or an option please let me know.

Comment: `As the lightning component embedded in Utility bar is not initialized until we open the utility bar` There is actually a checkbox that is for that, to pre-load or not the component (`Starts automatically`)

Comment: I am glad, I asked this here. Thank you @SergioAlcocer for pointing me in the right direction. This will definitely help me :)

Comment: Hi, I am experiencing something very similar, can you clarify this ability to 'pre-load' the component via a checkbox?

Comment: @Max If you open any utility item you will see "Start Automatically" checkbox towards the bottom of the page. If you check it, SF will pre-load the utility item as soon as you open it.